# How to write complex sort in python?

Tags: python

Is there a concise way to sort a list by first sorting numbers in ascending order and then sort the characters in descending order?

How would you sort the following:

`['2', '4', '1', '6', '7', '4', '2', 'K', 'A', 'Z', 'B', 'W']`

To:

`['1', '2', '2', '4', '4', '6', '7', 'Z', 'W', 'K', 'B', 'A']`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way (there might be better ones) is to separate digits and letters beforehand, sort them appropriately and glue them again together in the end:

```
lst = ['2', '4', '1', '6', '7', '4', '2', 'K', 'A', 'Z', 'B', 'W']

numbers = sorted([number for number in lst if number.isdigit()])
letters = sorted([letter for letter in lst if not letter.isdigit()], reverse=True)
combined = numbers + letters
print(combined)
```

---

Another way makes use of `ord(...)` and the ability to sort by tuples. Here we use zero for numbers and one for letters:

```
def sorter(item):
    if item.isdigit():
        return 0, int(item)
    else:
        return 1, -ord(item)

print(sorted(lst, key=sorter))
```

Both will yield

```
['1', '2', '2', '4', '4', '6', '7', 'Z', 'W', 'K', 'B', 'A']
```

---

As for timing:

```
def different_lists():
    global my_list
    numbers = sorted([number for number in my_list if number.isdigit()])
    letters = sorted([letter for letter in my_list if not letter.isdigit()], reverse=True)
    return numbers + letters

def key_function():
    global my_list
    def sorter(item):
        if item.isdigit():
            return 0, int(item)
        else:
            return 1, -ord(item)

    return sorted(my_list, key=sorter)

from timeit import timeit
print(timeit(different_lists, number=10**6))
print(timeit(key_function, number=10**6))
```

This yields (running it a million times on my MacBook):

```
2.9208732349999997
4.54283629
```

So the approach with list comprehensions is faster here.

Comment: One can use generator instead of list comprehension by removing square bracket

Comment: @GuillaumeJacquenot: Haven't tested it but I'm sure there's no real performance boost in using a generator here. Might be wrong though.

Comment: IMX the generator approach is usually actually slower - but it thrashes memory less (which *may* prevent a `MemoryError` if you need to sort something that takes up a large percentage of available memory), and is more elegant. Of course, you still need parentheses to use a generator expression for the `letters`, since there is more than one argument for the call.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Good to know. I've thought of another approach (in the updated answer), maybe there's an advantage when using generators.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on the custom-comparison approach: in Python the built-in sort does key comparison.

How to think about the problem: to group values and then sort each group by a different quality, we can think of "which group is a given value in?" as a quality - so now we are sorting by multiple qualities, which we do with a `key` that gives us a tuple of the value for each quality.

Since we want to sort the letters in descending order, and we can't "negate" them (in the arithmetic sense), it will be easiest to apply `reverse=True` to the entire sort, so we keep that in mind.

We encode: `True` for digits and `False` for non-digits (since numerically, these are equivalent to `1` and `0` respectively, and we are sorting in descending order overall). Then for the second value, we'll use the symbol directly for non-digits; for digits, we need the negation of the numeric value, to re-reverse the sort.

This gives us:

```
def custom_key(value):
    numeric = value.isdigit()
    return (numeric, -int(value) if numeric else value)
```

And now we can do:

```
my_list.sort(key=custom_key, reverse=True)
```

which works for me (and also handles multi-digit numbers):

```
>>> my_list
['1', '2', '2', '4', '4', '6', '7', 'Z', 'W', 'K', 'B', 'A']
```

Comment: You *can*, of course, "negate" the strings using `ord`, and you can even make that work for longer strings by mapping `ord` onto each character. This seems more elegant to me, though. Notice that there isn't a requirement for all the tuples to have the same types in each position - as long as comparisons between incompatible types aren't ever required. We can guarantee that statically here.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement your own comparison function and pass it as the `key` argument for the `sorted` function. What you are seeking is not a trivial comparison as you "assign" custom values to fields so you will have to let Python know how you value each one of them

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question... The question is basically what would be that `key`...